# How to find all symlinks in directory and its subdirectories in python

Tags: python

I need to list symlinks using python. Broken aswell

How do I do it? I was searching everywhere and tried alot.

The best result I found was:

```
import os,sys
print '\n'.join([os.path.join(sys.argv[1],i) 
    for i in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]) if 
    os.path.islink(os.path.join(sys.argv[1],i))])
```

It does not show where its linked to and it doesn't go to subdirs.

Comment: If you want to go to subdirs, please use `os.walk(followlinks=True)`. If you want to show the link target, please use `os.readlink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a code similar to this one to achieve what you need. Directories to search are passed as arguments or current directory taken as the default. You can modify this further with the `os.walk` method to make it recursive.

```
import sys, os

def lll(dirname):
    for name in os.listdir(dirname):
        if name not in (os.curdir, os.pardir):
            full = os.path.join(dirname, name)
            if os.path.isdir(full) and not os.path.islink(full):
                lll(full)
            elif os.path.islink(full):
                print(name, '->', os.readlink(full))
def main(args):
    if not args: args = [os.curdir]
    first = 1
    for arg in args:
        if len(args) > 1:
            if not first: print()
            first = 0
            print(arg + ':')
        lll(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Tools/scripts/lll.py

Comment: ah yes i've found this and added os.walk but its still not showing subdirs