# How to only list symlinks when walking through directory in Python?

Tags: python, operating-system, symlink, os.walk

I need to update hundreds of symlinks in a nested directory. I tried using `os.walk` with `followlinks=True` but it was giving me subdirectories and stuff.

Let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
output/
output/subdirectory_1/file_1.txt
output/subdirectory_2/file_2.txt
output/subdirectory_2/symlink_1.txt
output/subdirectory_2/subdirectory_2a/symlink_2.txt
output/symlink_3.txt
output/file_3.txt
```

**How can I use `os.walk` (or something else in the standard library) that can give me something similar to `glob`?** That is, like the following (order doesn't matter):

```
for fp in [INSERT FUNCTION]:
    print(fp)


output/subdirectory_2/symlink_1.txt
output/subdirectory_2/subdirectory_2a/symlink_2.txt
output/symlink_3.txt
```

EDIT:
This is my current code, is this the preferred method?

```
In [8]: symlinks = list()
   ...: for i, path in pv(enumerate(os.walk(".", followlinks=True))):
   ...:     parent_directory, subdirectories, files = path
   ...:     for name in subdirectories + files:
   ...:         path_child = os.path.join(parent_directory, name)
   ...:         if os.path.islink(path_child):
   ...:             print(path_child)
```

Comment: Use `os.walk` but check `os.path.islink()` on each file.

Comment: Does this question help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068419/how-to-check-if-file-is-a-symlink-in-python

Comment: I prefer CPython code :-). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62079423/how-to-find-all-symlinks-in-directory-and-its-subdirectories-in-python